# How to get month and year from date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I need help to get month and year from a date which is in yyyymmdd format.

The dates look like this, '20150102', the output should be Jan 2015.

I want the output as on single value, currently using datepart function Im getting output in 2 different columns for month and year

Comment: Check `Date_format()` function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may help:

SQL Server:

```
SELECT FORMAT (GETDATE(), 'MMM yyyy')  -- Jul 2019
SELECT FORMAT (GETDATE(), 'MMMM yyyy') -- July 2019
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 106), 8) -- Jul 2019
```

For more details: https://www.tutorialgateway.org/sql-date-format/

MySQL:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("20150102", "%M %Y");  -- January 2015
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("20150102", "%b %Y"); -- Jan 2015
SELECT YEAR(date) AS 'year', MONTH(date) AS 'month'
```

For more details: http://www.sqlines.com/mysql-to-oracle/date_format

Comment: thank you Khairul but this didnt work, I need the output for a date field which is in yyyymmdd format to give me the monthname and year

Comment: See second line, it's out is as your requirement

Comment: Actually, I guess the tag earlier was not specifying that this requirement is for SQL Server. Is that the reason this solution is not going through?

Comment: thanks Khairul, this works, however how would i use order by in such a case such that I get the ouput in chronological order. I want to see count of sales by this month year field, so it should give out output as Jan 2015 - 1000, Feb 2015 - 2000 and so on. Currently its giving Jan 2015 -1000, Jan 2016 -5000. Does that make sense?

Comment: I guess what im asking is how to write the order by clause here

Comment: My query is as follows:SELECT FORMAT (cast(Recent_enrollment_date as date), 'MMM  yyyy') as timeperiod, count(*) as count
 from
 tablename
 group by FORMAT (cast(Recent_enrollment_date as date), 'MMM  yyyy') 
 order by 1

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will recognize the date string as a date, so you can use `date_format()` to get the format you want:

```
select date_format('20150102', '%b %Y')
```

Comment: thanks Gordon, its giving me an error saying, DATE_FORMAT' is not a recognized built-in function name. Also, my requirement is not just for this particular field but for an entire column.

Answer (score 0):

there is a list of all differnet sql date formats [sql date formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)